# Javascript Input Format

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what would be the best way to store input like: 
[99.90, 76.00, 67.76, 56.78]
into 4 separate variables (the 4 different numbers into their own variable).  I would know how to do so in C, but I'm new to Javascript and I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that input a string or an array?

Comment: Your question needs more detail. If you want to store something in four variables, then do so. What's stopping you? Are you asking on how to parse the data? How to read it?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I'm essentially asking how I could for example do this:
It was be a string input of "[99.90, 76.00, 67.76, 56.78]", and I'm curious as how to grab each set of numbers so it would be something like this;
a = 99.90, b = 76.00, c = 67.76, d = 56.78

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you could just use an array:

```
var myArray = [99.90, 76.00, 67.76, 56.78];
console.log(myArray[0]) //logs 99.90
```

If your input is a string, you could also do this:

```
var input = "[99.90, 76.00, 67.76, 56.78]";
input = input.replace(/\[\]/g, '');
var myArray = input.split(',');
console.log(myArray[0]) //logs 99.90
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on php method

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gsantos/b414ub3e/

```
/**
 * Method list (based on PHP list)
 */
Array.prototype.list = Array.prototype.list || function () {

    var list = this,
        listIndex = 0,
        listTotal,
        listValue,
        variables = arguments,
        variableValue,
        variablesIndex = 0;

    listTotal = list.length;

    for (; listIndex < listTotal; listIndex += 1) {
        variableValue = variables[listIndex]
        listValue = list[listIndex]; 
        if ("undefined" !== typeof variableValue) {
            window[variableValue] = listValue;
        }
    }

    return this;
}

// example
var myArray = [99.90, 76.00, 67.76, 56.78];
myArray.list("a", "b", "c", "d");

alert(a);
```